# Use <wbr> in FormattedMessage as value (with TypeScript)

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript, react-intl

I am trying to use the [*optional word break tag* `<wbr>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/wbr) in a message for `<FormattedMessage id="some:message" />`.

#### Background

Some words/texts are to large for some parent elements on mobile screens and we are using a column like layout, which we cannot replace for mobile environments easily.

#### Idea

Like `{p: function p(textFrag: string) :JSX.Element { return (<p>{textFrag}</p>); }}`:

We could use something like `<FormattedMessage id="some:message" />`,

```
{"some:message": "This is a very<wbr>very<wbr>long<wbr>word"} // as message

{wbr: function wbr() :JSX.Element { return (<wbr>); }}
// or
{wbr: function wbr() :JSX.Element { return (<React.Fragment><wbr></React.Fragment>); }}
```

But I am getting just a

```
JSX element 'React.Fragment' has no corresponding closing tag.ts(17008)
```

for the latter example and two error messages:

```
JSX element 'wbr' has no corresponding closing tag.ts(17008)
// plus
Unexpected token. Did you mean `{'}'}` or `&rbrace;`?ts(1381)
```

for the former.

#### Alternative

Is there any alternative for optional word breaks? Or any solution for `<FormattedMessage>` and *ReactIntl*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSX specs is a bit different to HTML one. In JSX, you need to use a self-closing tag like this:

```
<wbr />
```

This is valid in HTML but not in JSX:

```
<wbr>
```